# Laravel middleware doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, laravel, api, paypal, e-commerce

I am using Laravel 8 as backend and Angular 11 as frontend. I want to pass three parameters to Laravel with an API from my frontend after a purchase using the url. This will look like this: `.../{user_id}/${track_id}/${price_id}`.
I don't know if it's the best way to confirm a purchase, but unfortunately I don't know of any other, even after a lot of research. The only problem with it is that it would be very vulnerable and one could just write in any numbers with e.g. Postman, so the products would end up in their accounts.

Now I tried in my **api.php**:

```
Route::post('addTrackusers/{user_id}/{track_id}/{track_pice}', 'App\Http\Controllers\trackusersController@addTrackusers')->middleware(['auth:api', Payout::class]);
```

With the help of this route I get the required three parameters. After that, however, I want to use middleware to prevent unauthorized users from passing any parameters that haven't bought anything:

**Middleware/Payout.php**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        if ($request->id != $user->id) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

I'm really not sure how to fix the problem. My thought was to pass the three parameters and compare if they belong to the current user.

But also the current user could just enter his token in Postman, then he would be authorized to pass three parameters. I would really appreciate any advice or how best to fix this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->user_id !== auth()->user()->id) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action');
        }
        
        return $next($request); 
    }
```

In your url, you don't have $id, but $user_id

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that, thank you so much! Now it works! Do you think it's a good idea to approach the purchase process this way? I notice that it is quite vulnerable, and that the route can be exploited by users who are currently logged in, since they only need to enter their token.

Comment: You shoul think about using laravel sanctum ou laravel passport. You can generate tokens with scope to a user or to some group or role.

Comment: Why you need to pass user_id by url? And what the meaning of track_id and track_price?

Comment: I understand, thanks for the advice. With the ``user_id`` I wanted to pass the currently logged in user, ``track_id`` is the product ID that the user has purchased and ``track_price`` should represent the price for the purchased product.  But I think it has been very unnecessary and above all very vulnerable.

Comment: I just haven't found another way to tell my backend which items were purchased, at what price, and by whom.

Comment: Why you don't use session or even database table to record this purchase?

Comment: The main problem is with my Angular frontend. It was not planned to use a backend, so the backend is not involved in my frontend at all and I have been working without a backend for a year now. Now, after the backend comes into play, I can't even edit all that and connect to the backend, as I am also too inexperienced to be able to solve the problem. I have sample data in my frontend that all interact with each other. Unfortunately the backend is only for logging in, registering and saving users to their products.

Comment: If you want, I can give you tips to you do an admin to manage your shop.

Comment: I would really appreciate it!